# Conflict between two jquery plugins (dragscrollable and scrollto)

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to implement something similar to [this](http://tv.sky.com/tvlistings), in which I can drag the content of a div and also click and scroll to element. I managed to find those two plugins, [dragscrollable](http://hitconsultants.com/dragscroll_scrollsync/scrollpane.html) and [scrollto](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/), each plugin is working alone on my div perfectly but when I add the two plugins together there seems to be a conflict between the mousedown and click event, I mean when I hold down the mouse to drag, the drag occurs successfully when I release the mouse, but then am scrolled back to the element which I held the mouse on to start dragging as if I clicked on the element. I know that a click is a sequence of mouse down and mouse up, but is there any way to differentiate between holding down the mouse and releasing it to start dragging and then stop on the location where I released the mouse and between clicking on an element inside the div to scroll to it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at the other mouse events jquery offers. You could do the dragging with a combination of mousedown and mousemove. If the mouse has moved a long way then you could cancel any click handler you have as it must have been a drag and not a single click.

Have a look at:
http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/
http://api.jquery.com/mousemove/
http://api.jquery.com/mouseup/

Comment: The dragging is already implemented using a combination of mousedown and mousemove and the scrollTo action  is implemented through the click handler. Knowing how long the mouse moved would be inside the mousemove handler, right? But I don't know how would I cancel the click from inside the move.